# LDAP port forwarding or proxy

Tags: proxy, ldap, port-forwarding, oid

I am trying to find a way to locally access an OID server (via LDAP) that is usually only accessible from my app's staging server. I have login credentials for the staging box. I do not have login credentials on the machine that is running the OID server. If I did I would simply use an ssh tunnel. What I think I want to do is forward my local outgoing LDAP request through the staging server to the OID server. How can this be done? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an SSH server running on your staging box and your LDAP server is reachable via unencrypted LDAP on the standard port, you could try the following:

```
ssh -L 10389:yourldapserver:389 username@yourstagingserver
```

which will connect port 10389 on your local machine (127.0.0.1) with port 389 on your LDAP server.

*yourldapserver* is the hostname or IP of your LDAP server as seen by the staging machine, *yourstagingserver* is the hostname or IP of your staging server as seen by your local machine and *username* is your login name on that box.